# Rails - updating flash message after asynchronous job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd

I am using beanstalkd plus backburner to run asynchronous jobs and I want to automatically update the flash message with some information after each job finishes executing.

I can get the flash message on the controller after a job finishes executing. After a page refresh, the flash message appears. But what I want, is the message to appear by itself. How can I do that?

Comment: The only way you can update a web page with the results of an asynchronous task is to constantly poll the server and see if the thing is done, and there's no easy way to do that. You'd have to create a controller that checked the status, and set up JavaScript polling loop to regularly hit the server and check the status. The web simply doesn't do push updates.

Comment: Take a look at this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

Comment: Hi @JimStewart, thanks for the help. You were right and yesterday I searched for gems that could help me. Finaly, I found private_pub and solved my problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been toying with this idea for a while,

something that avoids polling or setting up of websockets to do pushing,

one approach is to create a table of pending flash messages, index it by `created_at`, make it a has_many relationship of the user model and set a `before_filter` on application controller to render the flash messages that happened after `last_request_at`.

You set up a nice user method called `User#message` for example and say `some_user.message "blah blah"` and it'll render the message to the user.

Downside is a lot of possible db spam but since the flash message table is just timestamps, foreign key and a string column this should actually be pretty performant. However, considering your choice of beanstalkd this might not be an optimal solution for you.

Plan B (assuming you don't need the flashes to be persistent) you can keep the messages in `Rails.cache` and just clear the cache when you render.

A/B hybrid solution is to put these messages into something like mongo, redis etc

Just make sure it's all wrapped up in a nice, abstract API like `some_user.message` and you can switch between different approaches later on with ease

Comment: Your three possible solutions may all work. However I opted to use private_pub to do it and it works pretty well! Thanks for the help!